# withField in Spark SQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, struct, apache-spark-sql

In PySpark, we can use [**`withField`**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.Column.withField.html#pyspark.sql.Column.withField):

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([((1,),)], ['mystruct'])
df = df.withColumn('mystruct', F.col('mystruct').withField('n', F.lit(3)))

df.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- mystruct: struct (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- _1: long (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- n: integer (nullable = false)
```

**How to use this in Spark SQL?**

I've tried looking at the logical plan and applying the result to `expr`:

```py
df.explain(True)
# == Parsed Logical Plan ==
# 'Project [update_fields('mystruct, WithField(n, 3)) AS mystruct#84]
# +- LogicalRDD [mystruct#82], false
# ...

df = spark.createDataFrame([((1,),)], ['mystruct'])
df = df.withColumn('mystruct', F.expr("update_fields(mystruct, WithField(n, 3))"))
```

> Undefined function: update_fields. This function is neither a built-in/temporary function, nor a persistent function that is qualified as spark_catalog.default.update_fields.; line 1 pos 0

Comment: Still unresolved https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-22231, although method for `Column` is already there (as you know :))

Comment: In case others find this Quality has added update_field and drop_field as sql functions [impl is here](https://github.com/sparkutils/quality/blob/main/src/main/scala/com/sparkutils/quality/impl/util/StructFunctions.scala).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this time, there no such support for SQL API.

You'll have to recreate the whole struct in order to update it, using either `named_struct` or `struct` functions.

To reference existing fields, you can use `mystruct.*` as pointed in comments by @samkart:

```py
df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")

df = spark.sql("SELECT struct(mystruct.*, 3 as n) as mystruct FROM df")

df.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- mystruct: struct (nullable = false)
#  |    |-- _1: long (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- n: integer (nullable = false)
```

Note that you're looking at the logical plan, if you look at the physical plan you'll see the sql expression being applied:

```py
# == Physical Plan ==
# *(1) Project [if (isnull(mystruct#0)) null else named_struct(_1, mystruct#0._1, n, 3) AS mystruct#2]
# +- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[mystruct#0]
```

Comment: Thank you! Are you aware of a way without explicitly listing all the existent struct field names?

Comment: @ZygD wouldn't `mystruct.*` work in sql?

Comment: @ZygD I mean: `F.expr(f"struct({','.join([f'mystruct.{f} as {f}' for f in df.select('mystruct.*').columns])}, 3 as n)")` but as I said this is not plain SQL :)

Comment: @blackbishop - `spark.sql('select col_struct, struct(col_struct.*, col_struct.val * 2 as val_2) as new_struct from temp_tbl').show()` this seems to work in my case. spark 3.1.3 -- did you mean something else? a `printSchema()` confirmed that the names have also been retained

Comment: @samkart Thanks!! I always thought this is not working when creating a new struct. Maybe I was confused with the fact that it doesn't work inside `transform` function when updating array of structs... Learning everyday something new :)