# Cast struct field without losing struct type in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, date, pyspark, casting

I have the following dataFrame

```
|—- id: long
|—- user: struct
     |—- name: string
     |—- date: string
```

When I run the following code:

```
df = df.select(
            F.col(“id”),
            F.col(“user.name”),
            F.col(“user.date”).cast(“date”)
     )
```

I get the following schema

```
   |—- id: long
   |—- user.name: string
   |—- user.date: date
```

How can I cast the date without losing the struct? My desired output is:

```
|—- id: long
|—- user: struct
     |—- name: string
     |—- date: date
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with **`withField`** function.

**`Example:`**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
ds = "{'id':1, 'user':{'name':'abc','date':'2022-02-12'}}"
df = spark.read.json(sc.parallelize([ds]), multiLine=True)
df1 = df.withColumn("user", col("user").withField("date", col("user.date").cast("date")))

df1.show(10,False)
#+---+-----------------+
#|id |user             |
#+---+-----------------+
#|1  |{2022-02-12, abc}|
#+---+-----------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

[withField in Spark SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73220890/withfield-in-spark-sql) gives an example of how to do it with the DSL but also points out that it's not available in the standard sql functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
df2 = df.selectExpr(
    "id",
    "STRUCT (CAST (user.name AS STRING), CAST (user.date AS DATE)) as user"
)

df2.printSchema()

root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- user: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- col1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- col2: date (nullable = true)
```